# Javabean naming convention

Tags: java

**Question** : Which are methods using JavaBeans naming conventions for accessors and mutators?
The code above was one of the correct answer:

```
public getNumWings() {return numberWings;}
```

I checked the beans [definition](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) (section 8.3 clarify a little more) and from what I read (and knew) I would say the getter has a wrong name, Is this answer really correct? If it is, is because a new property "numWings" is "created/exposed"?

Comment: It's wrong because a variable named "foo" should have a getter named "getFoo".  Your write answer is "getNumberWings".  Unless I misunderstand, it might be a case of incorrect study materials.

Comment: @duffymo I agree with you, but I was wondering it there is a reason for why this option would be acceptable

Comment: I don't know; perhaps I don't understand the naming convention as well as I should.  Personally, I think it would mystify most of the people I know who write Java.  Here's the acid test: If Jackson fails to serialize this variable using that form of the function, then I'd say it's wrong.  The point of getting a useless certification should not be to dredge up obscure minutia like this; it should be to teach you how to write clear code that anyone understands.  This makes that objective harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaBeans specification is concerned with *properties*, not fields. Although it's common for properties to be backed by simple fields with the same names, there's no requirement to do so, and a number of properties (particularly booleans such as `isEmpty()`) are often computed on the fly.

In this example, the `getNumWings()` accessor is a getter for a property named `numWings`, and there's no problem. The fact that the property is backed by a field with a different name is a private implementation detail and irrelevant as far as the bean interface is concerned.